# Handle Auto Renew Subscription iOS SDK

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

I am developing an app which requires auto renew subscription monthly and I want to maintain that on per user basis who logged into my app. is it possible anyhow with in app purchase. Also how can we handle cancelation of subscriptions ?
I want to maintain all this on my own server.

Comment: side note: Apple is currently reviewing the auto-renew subscription in-app purchase items **strictly**; higher chance to get approved if your app is a newsstand app.

Comment: my app is not a newsstand app but we have credits system like unlimited credits per month. any suggestions ?

Comment: the approval decision is made by Apple. I bet you've read [this guideline / getting started](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf). If your app & the IAP item are following these guidelines, you can submit to Apple for review (to test whether your IAP item is ready for subscription model).

Comment: @RahulVyas: Can you please provide the code if you have implemented it? I have done it using https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit  but have few questions. Is this auto renewable in app purchase restorable? 2) If I have done purchased one in app product id then even if I change this, it automatically gets purchased. Can you help me if you have done this?

Comment: @Manthan I haven't implemented this thing yet but I guess the answer below might help you to implement the same.

Answer (score 2):

In the [StoreKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6), it mentioned in Cancellation section:

> A subscription is paid for in full when it’s purchased and can be
>   refunded only by contacting Apple customer service. For example, if
>   the user accidentally buys the wrong product, customer support can
>   cancel the subscription and issue a refund. It’s not possible for
>   customers to change their mind in the middle of a subscription period
>   and decide they don’t want to pay for the rest of the subscription.
>
> **To check whether a purchase has been canceled, look for the
>   Cancellation Date field in the receipt**. If the field has a date in it,
>   regardless of the subscription’s expiration date, the purchase has
>   been canceled—treat a canceled receipt the same as if no purchase had
>   ever been made.
>
> Depending on the type of product, you may be able to check only the
>   currently active subscription, or you may need to check all past
>   subscriptions. For example, a magazine app would need to check all
>   past subscriptions to determine which issues the user had access to.

Bear in mind that users can [cancel the subscription anytime without opening your App](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202039). Therefore, you have to check the status of subscription every time the user logs into your App.

Comment: I have one case here. Suppose User 1 logged into app and buys the subscription. now user 2 logged into the app on same device.User 2 tries to buy subscription and he get success as user 1 has already subscribed now if apple device owner cancels the subscription how do I cancel subscription for user 1 and 2 on my server? is there a way to uniquely identify subscription?

Comment: this is a good question. [This article](https://www.airpair.com/ios/posts/swift-storekit-in-app-purchases) (scroll down to *Finds the Unicorn*) mentions how to uniquely identify the user. Didn't try on subscription model, but it should work. Let us know if the unique identifier can't work on your case.